# Output predicted image Tensorflow Lite

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to figure out how i can save a predicted mask (output) from a tensorflow model which have been converted to a tf.lite model on my PC. Any tips or ideas of how i can vizualise it or save the predicted mask as a .png image. I have tried using the tensorflow Lite interference from https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/inference#load_and_run_a_model_in_python without success.

Output now is as following:

```
[  1 512 512   3]
[[[[9.7955531e-01 2.0444747e-02]
   [9.9987805e-01 1.2197520e-04]
   [9.9978799e-01 2.1196880e-04]
   .......
   .......
   [9.9997246e-01 2.7536058e-05]
   [9.9997437e-01 2.5645388e-05]
   [1.9125430e-03 9.9808747e-01]]]]
```

Any help is greatly appriceated.
Many thanks

```
## Load the TFLite model and allocate tensors. 
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path="tflite_model.tflite")
print(interpreter.get_input_details())
print(interpreter.get_output_details())
print(interpreter.get_tensor_details())
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

## Get input and output tensors.
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

## Test the model on input data.
input_shape = input_details[0]['shape']
print(input_shape)

## Use same image as Keras model
input_data = np.array(Xall, dtype=np.float32)
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_data)

interpreter.invoke()

## The function `get_tensor()` returns a copy of the tensor data.
## Use `tensor()` in order to get a pointer to the tensor.
output_data = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
print(output_data)
output_data.shape
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the meaning of your model output. Then, use image libraries like `cv2` or `PIL` to draw the mask.

For example, the first row:

```
  9.7955531e-01 2.0444747e-02
```

You need to figure out what they correspond to. With the limited information, it is hard to guess from the context.

Comment: Thank you, i am new to this and just the explanation of it being the rows made it more clear. thanks again!